# Problems with firewall bloking calls to DRIVE API

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth, firewall

I'm using Google drive api V2 to develop an application (server to server), when Ii put this application into my server I have a lot of problems with the firewall rules.

Currently i already enabled the following hosts in my firewall:

```
accounts.google.com 443
www.googleapis.com 443
googleapis.com 443
```

Does someone knows the complete list of hosts?

Comment: Hosts look correct to me you have both the authentication server and the google APIs endpoints.   They are both https so 443 should also be the correct port.  There used to be some documentation on this but that's was like five years ago I looked for it couldn't find it again.

Comment: What problems are you having? Have you logged any firewall rejections?

Answer (score 0):

i solve the problem using this https://support.google.com/a/answer/2589954?hl=pt-BR list in my firewall